# QGIS 3.14 with GRASS 7 error on batch dxf export

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dxf

I tried to do a batch export of 19 geopackage layers to dxf and got an error I don't understand (I don't speak Python very well). First error of 19 pasted in below from my log, all of them the same.

> **Processing algorithm 1/19…**
> Algorithm v.out.dxf starting…
> Input parameters:
> {'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER': 0.0001,
> 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': None,
> 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER': -1.0,
> 'input': '1_634370ab_e31a_4d68_91b9_bdbacd5dc470',
> 'output': 'H:/Data/Vector/map/layers/2.dxf'}

> g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs"
> v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="H:\Data\Vector\map\layers\1.gpkg" layer="1" output="vector_5fb0b2ffecf5f2" --overwrite -o
> g.region n=42.1083199772876 s=42.0816710148285 e=-74.4838672516787 w=-74.5197998630435
> v.out.dxf input=vector_5fb0b2ffecf5f2 output="H:/Data/Vector/map/layers/2.dxf" --overwrite

> **Starting GRASS GIS...**
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 434, in processAlgorithm
> Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 401, in executeGrass
> feedback.reportError(line.strip())
> TypeError: reportError() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fatalError'

> Algorithm v.out.dxf failed…
> Execution failed after 0.73 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

Can you try the following
In the `v.out.dxf` dialog window pull down the "Advanced parameters", then in the "GRASS GIS 7 Region" click the ellipsis and select "Calculate from layer" and select your export layer. And then "Run".

Second suggestion:

Why would you go from a geopackage, inport to GRASS only to then export to DXF? Why not simply run a loop using `ogr2ogr`, directly from *.gpkg to *.dxf? Something like: (depending on your command shell)

```
for f in *.gpkg; do
dxf=`basename ${f} .gpkg`.dxf
ogr2ogr -f DXF ${dxf} ${f}
done
```

??

HTH

Comment: I didn't use ogr2ogr because I was using the GRASS toolbox inside QGIS. I ended up using the GDAL "convert format" tool and that worked fine. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try the ogr2ogr next time =)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't end up getting the GRASS tool to work within QGIS, but I used the GDAL "convert format" tool and that worked well enough.